# Why is the Specific Heat of Helium 36 times greater than Xenon?

Tags: thermodynamics

Given that these are single atoms, why should the specific heat difference be so great? And more specifically, why does it take 36 times as much energy to raise the temperature of a given mass of Helium compared to Xenon?

Comment: How does it compare on a per-mole basis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key question is *"Per mole or per gram?"* Because the both values can be found tabulated as "specific heat" in various sources. Perhaps it would be useful to distinguish "molar specific heat" from "specific heat per unit mass".

You seem to be using the intuition for the molar quantity, so if the table is by mass, the answer is simply that you need more moles of helium.

Comment: By mass. But why should the number of molecules matter?

Comment: Because temperature is related to the average energy *per mode*, and when there are more particles there are more modes.

Comment: Intuitively, temperature equals velocity and energy is proportional to mass, but since we are talking identical masses the energy should be the same. Can you provide an intuitive explanation?

Comment: Err ... *"Intuitively, temperature equals velocity"* Is wrong two ways. First, temperature is proportional to the energy not the velocity, and secondly it is the average energy per mode, not the total (which should be very clear because total energy is extensive and temperature is intensive). So for a change in energy $\Delta E$ the temperature change is proportional to $\Delta E/N$ where $N$ is the number of modes (which reduces to the number of atoms for an ideal gas).

Comment: Start with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinetic_theory.

Comment: So where is the energy actually being stored in the atoms if not as (entirely) velocity?

Comment: In a kinetic gas it *is* the kinetic energy, but that is proportional to velocity *squared*. For systems that are not non-interacting there are also potential terms.

Comment: In an ideal gas atoms have three degrees of freedom, the $x$, $y$ and $z$ directions, and each DOF gets about $\tfrac{1}{2}kT$ of energy. So the total internal energy is $\tfrac{3}{2}kT$ times the number of atoms.